# Optimize removing duplicates and using groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df where there are duplicates that exist across two columns (ID and col4). I don't want to simply just keep the first one. I want to take whichever one of those duplicates has a value in the 'verified' column. If there is multiple rows with a value in that column, just take the first row that has a verified value. If none of the duplicates have verified rows, then just keep the first duplicate. It is important that all of the rows have a name value. If they don't have a name value, put NaN as the ID value. I also want to have a list of all of the IDs that don't have a name.

original

```
df_IDs=
name           ID       verified    ID2        col4
joe            123      213         943          1
sally          123                  943          1
sarah          342                  221          2
mary           342      643         222          ...  
adam           342      932         223          ...
sam            214                   ...         ...
jill           214                   ...         ...
jack           992                   ...         ...
NaN            379                   ...         ...
NaN            579                   ...         ...
```

desired

```
df_IDs=
name           ID       verified    ID2    col4 
joe            123      213         943     ...
sarah          342                  221
mary           342      643         222
adam           342      932         223
sam            214         
jack           992
NaN           379   
NaN           579         

no_match=[ID/379, ID/579]
```

what I've tried, but it is taking quite a while for it to run on 15 million lines. Is there a way to optimize this?

```
df2 = df2.loc[df2['verified'].notna().groupby([df['ID'], df['col4']], sort=False).idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
df2[df2['verified'].notna()].drop_duplicates(['ID','col4'])
```